# Сделал проверку для загрузки файлов, если больше 5 мб то выводить сообщение, что файл большой.

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Дело в том, что в общем все работает, работал с одними файлами, меньше и больше 5 мб. Все работало, скрипт отвечал, но потом решил другие файлы проверить, больше 10мб скрипт выводит что загружено, почему? Проверил около 10 файлов с размером больше 5 мб, некоторые загружает а некоторые нет. Это в chrome проверял, а в mozilla firefox вообще загружаю файл меньше 5 мб, ответ приходит, что он больше 5 мб. Что за фигня?
Вот обработчик

```
if($_FILES['myfile']){
    if(file_type($_FILES['myfile']['type']) AND $_FILES['myfile']['size'] < 5242880){
        $dir = "../demo/";
        $file_name = date("dyHmis");
        $file_type = file_type($_FILES['myfile']['type']);              
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], "$dir$file_name$file_type")){
            $namemuz = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
            $str = substr($namemuz, 0, -4);
            $direct = "http://mackay.kz/music/demo/";
            $urltrack = "$direct$file_name$file_type";

                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `mackaykz_music`.`demos` (`namedemo`, `link`) VALUES ('$str', '$urltrack');");
            }   
    }else{      
            echo 'недопустимо';     
    }   
}
```

Вот js

```
    onComplete : function(file, result) {
              if(result == "недопустимо"){
                  $("#uploadtrack").text('Загрузка трека');
                  $("#filemassage").html('Извините, но файл привышает размер 5 мб.');
                  this.enable();                  
              }else{
                  $("#uploadtrack").text('Загрузка трека').animate({position: 'relative', top: '-45px'},60);
                   $("#sendermodalwin").fadeIn(50).animate({position: 'relative', top: '-54px'},60);                       
                   var str = file.substring(0, file.length - 4);
                    $('#namedemostrokes').text(str);    
                  $("#filemassage").html('Демка была загружена: <br>' + str +' <br><audio autoplay controls src="' + result +'" ></audio>');
                    $("#linkdemomain").text(result);                      
                  this.enable();                  
              }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Проверяйте

```
$_FILES['myfile']['error']
```

Там содержится код ошибки, а значит загрузка не была завершена, поэтому размер файла 0, что меньше 5млн по условию проверки.
Помимо этого Ваш код уязвим к SQL-инъекциям по двум позициям: в filename и mime можно передать что угодно. Проверяйте эти данные прежде чем вставлять их в запрос к базе данных.

Comment: насчет инъекции знаю, хочу сначала с загрузкой разобраться, потом буду PDO рассматривать. Сейчас в хроме все работает, но мазиле так же, загружаю файл менее 5мб говорит что он больше 5мб, хотя в хроме все ок. Почему так?